# Dynamic file header eclipse (c++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, file, dynamic, header

I'm using eclipse to program a microcontroller using c or c++.

My question, is there any way to add a comment template to a exsisting file. And if there is a way to do this, is there a way to make that header dynamic (example: Last Edited: system time (when saved))

PS: i have read about that copyright plugin. Mabey some extra info about that could also clear up some things :)

Comment: There is no C/C++. There is C. And there is C++. But there is no C/C++. Both languages have different idioms, don't mix your mind up by using C/C++. There isn't.

Comment: I'm using eclipse to program the two languages. I know that there different. But i assumed it was clear. i will edit the post for better readability

Comment: @phresnel i looked briefly into the copyright plugin, but i first wanted to exclude that eclipse does not have a build in function. Or there is a other work around.

Comment: I can't really help with eclipse. I just wanted to help improving your question :)

Comment: I just tried the copyright wizard plugin for eclipse. This is not the solution i want to go for. I don' t need copyright on my files. I just want to show in the top of the file, what the file is for, when it was first made, and (if possible) the date wich it was last edited (and by who) dynamicly